# Making AND and OR gates using the projection gate

Tags: digital-logic

Is it possible to make the AND logic gate or the OR logic gate by using only q or p projection gates?

The q projection gate truth table:

```
P Q R
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

The p projection gate truth table:

```
P Q R
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: What have you already considered in trying to answer this question for yourself?

Comment: I tested several combinations and I'm getting only variants of both projection logic gate outputs

Comment: I also tried adding XOR and NOT

Comment: I am assuming here that P and Q are the inputs and R is the output?

Comment: Yes, P and Q are the inputs and R is the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I am reading your notation properly, P and Q are the function inputs and R is the output.

For the q projection gate it looks like P is irrelevant and R = Q.  That is to say, for any value of Q, I can change P to any value and it doesn't affect the result.

for the p projection gate it looks like Q is irrelevant and R = P.  That is to say, for any value of P, I can change Q to any value and it doesn't affect the result.

So basically you have two gates where the output is just equal to the input.  From a logic circuit standpoint you could combine as many of these gates as you wanted, but ultimately the final output would just be equal to one of the inputs.  **It would not appear that there is any combination of gates that could yield any of the common functions such as AND, OR, NOT, XOR, NOR, NAND.**

Comment: Indeed, you can't have **combin**atorial logic unless you have gates which can *combine* (and also invert).   And it's a classic assignment to prove you can implement anything with enough instances of NAND or NOR alone.  But the "always get my way" gate is just a buffer.

Comment: Unless the electrical characteristics are such that you can safely short outputs together with a predictable result. And even then you need something that gives inversion.